# Return from first row if last row reached

Tags: mysql, sql

Table has an `id` column with rows 1 to 10. I want:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE id > 8 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 6
```

to return:

`9` `10` `1` `2` `3` `4`

What's the appropriate query for this?

Comment: And why are you draging this from the beyond?

Comment: Is there an issue with Barmar's answer?  I'm puzzled as to why a Bounty was added.  Sure, Barmar's answer is kludgy, but it may be the best.

Comment: Are the ids necessarily consecutive (no gaps)?  And are there any other unspecified assumptions?

Comment: You have already got good answers which gives what you want. Are you looking for something else ?

Comment: Why any database would get you rows having id 1,2,3,4 when the WHERE clause clearly says id > 8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM `table`
ORDER BY id <= 8, id
LIMIT 6
```

`id <= 8` will be false (0) for 9 and higher, true (1) for values lower than 9, so the higher values will be first. Then within each of those groups it orders by `id`.

Comment: `id < 8` will be `false` for `8` also. So you need `ORDER BY id <= 8...` or `ORDER BY id < 9...`

Comment: Seems good - demo here: https://rextester.com/WHLAE22300

Comment: Good answer. You can generalize this to ```SELECT id
FROM `table`
ORDER BY id <= (SELECT MAX(id) - 2 FROM `table`), id
LIMIT 6``` for tables with an arbitrary number of ids.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any sql-like syntax

```
SELECT id
FROM `table`
ORDER BY case when id > 8 then 1 else 2 end, id
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation that uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN id > 8 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id) AS rn
FROM `table`
ORDER BY rn LIMIT 6;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a44fac452be5bffb3ffc2f9baef8ad7)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > 8 ORDER BY id
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE id <= 8 ORDER BY id
) temp LIMIT 6;
```